# ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT in nodejs

Tags: node.js, paypal

To explain quickly, I am setting up paypal payment on nodejs.

The problem is that I have the following error when redirecting to paypal:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]:
> Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

I have searched on my side and of course it has a link with the asynchronous js but here I have trouble understanding.

Knowing that without the function "inscriptionGo()" which is launched at the beginning, the link of rediraction functions correctly and I can proceed to the payment...

Here is the code:

```js
app.post('/commander', (request, response) => {
 
    inscriptionGo(request,response, (cb) => {//donc on l'inscrit le gars
 
    if((cb && request.body.nom) || (!cb && !request.body.nom)){
        console.log('les deux mails sont envoyés!!!cb:'+cb)
        var total = 0
        if(infosServ.urlServ != 'http://localhost:8080'){
              paypal.configure({
                'mode': 'sandbox', //sandbox or live
                'client_id': 'AZM6gfmmteSfgP_UmjkC6tKhObpepWTcoY10cMzda5507Jco9879GnoH6BlPXLjy9pMJzvERS-HE8cph',
                'client_secret': 'ELu2gj8VpEEgM3SrL5ucrk1NFoAx9caSg9wBNHt3T-s1EHIrsGriVeCBsxi1blunNsFeGFxGuNmNLcaK'
                });
            }
      
         
        var initPaiement = 0;
         
        for(let i = 0; i < Object.keys(request.body).length; i++)
        {
         
            var idProduit = request.body['idProduit'+i]
            var articleNom = request.body['nom'+idProduit]
            var articlePrix = request.body['prix'+idProduit]
            var articleQt = request.body['quantite'+idProduit]
         
            if( request.body['idProduit'+i] != null || request.body['idProduit'+i] !== undefined){
                 
                if(!initPaiement ){
                var strCommProduits = idProduit;
                var strCommPrix = extraitNombre(articlePrix);
                var strCommQte = parseInt(extraitNombre(articleQt));
         
                    var create_payment_json = {
                        "intent": "sale",
                        "payer": {
                            "payment_method": "paypal"
                        },
                        "redirect_urls": {
                            "return_url": infosServ.urlServ+"/success",
                            "cancel_url": infosServ.urlServ+"/cancel"
                        },
                        "transactions": [{
                            "item_list": {
                                "items": [{
                                    "name": articleNom,
                                    "sku": "Produit produit en france",
                                    "price": extraitNombre(articlePrix),
                                    "currency": "EUR",
                                    "quantity": parseInt(extraitNombre(articleQt))
                                }]
                            },
                            "amount": {
                                "currency": "EUR",
                                "total": total
                            },
                            "description": "Produits"
                        }]
                    };
         
                    initPaiement = 1;
         
                }
                else if(initPaiement)
                {
                    strCommProduits += '_' + idProduit;
                    strCommPrix += '_' + extraitNombre(articlePrix);
                    strCommQte += '_' + parseInt(extraitNombre(articleQt));
         
                    var addItem = {"name": articleNom,"sku":"Produit Konix CBD produit en france","price":extraitNombre(articlePrix),"currency":"EUR","quantity": parseInt(extraitNombre(articleQt))}
                    create_payment_json.transactions[0].item_list.items.push(addItem)
         
                }
                        total += parseInt(extraitNombre(articlePrix)) * parseInt(extraitNombre(articleQt))
            }
      
        }
            if(request.body.searchInput)
                var adresseLiv = request.body.searchInput.replace(/ /g, '');
            else
                var adresseLiv = 'cANDc';
         
            
            create_payment_json.redirect_urls.return_url = infosServ.urlServ+'/success?produits='+strCommProduits+'&prix='+strCommPrix+'&quantite='+strCommQte+'&total='+total+'&adresse='+adresseLiv;
            console.log('vérifions:'+ create_payment_json.redirect_urls.return_url)
 
            total += extraitNombre(request.body.livraison)
            var addItem = {"name": 'livraison',"sku":request.body.searchInput,"price":extraitNombre(request.body.livraison),"currency":"EUR","quantity": 1}
            var totalItems =  {"currency": 'EUR',"total":total}
            create_payment_json.transactions[0].item_list.items.push(addItem)
            create_payment_json.transactions[0].amount = totalItems
         
            console.log('create_payment_json:')
            console.log(Object.values(create_payment_json.transactions))
            paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json,  function (error, payment) {
                if (error) {
                    throw error;
                } else {
                    for(let i = 0; i < payment.links.length;i++){
         
                        if(payment.links[i].rel == 'approval_url'){
                            console.log('link redirection :'+ payment.links[i].href)
                            response.redirect(payment.links[i].href)
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
 
 
    }
    else if (!cb){
        response.redirect('panier')
    }
            
})
})
```

Comment: What is `inscriptionGo` and what does it do with `response`?

Comment: function inscriptionGo(request,response, callback) : it adds an account in database and sends 2 mails, if it's ok the callback is at 1

Comment: so does the function actually redirect to this?  `response.redirect(payment.links[i].href)`, or does it fail with that error?

Comment: the function tries to redirect to this link and crashes on redirection

Comment: does anyone have another idea?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The error of HTTP headers already being sent occurs when you try to send an HTTP redirect (which uses headers) after already having begun to send an HTTP response body. Redirect headers cannot be set after a response body; at that point, only HTML (meta refresh) or JavaScript-based redirects can be done.

---

In any case, you are using a [deprecated v1/payments SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK), and redirects away from your site, which are both things you should not be doing.

Instead, follow the current [PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) guide and implement 2 routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order' (see the optional step 5 in 'Add and modify the code', and you can use the current [@paypal/checkout-server-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/checkout-server-sdk)). Both routes should return only JSON data (no HTML nor redirect). Inside the second route, when the capture API is successful you should store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) immediately *before* forwarding your return JSON to the frontend caller.

Pair those 2 routes with the frontend approval, which keeps your site loaded during the process and does not redirect away: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server